# Custom query Parameter value [2] did not match expected type

Tags: spring, jpa

I trying to update a entity with OneToOne relation using restful web service.

I'm using a custom query but it doesnt work

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Activity a SET a.type = :type WHERE a.id = :uuid")
int setType(@Param("uuid") UUID uuid, @Param("type") long type);
```

Error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [com.mezoo.tdc.model.ActivityType (n/a)]

Activity Bean

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "Activity")
public class Activity implements Serializable{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
   @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
   @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
   private UUID uuid;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE})
   @JoinColumn(name="type", nullable = false)
   private ActivityType type;
```

ActivityType Bean

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "ActivityType")
public class ActivityType implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String code;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String label;
```

It is possible to update without custom queries ?
I would like use POST request like below :

> {"uuid":"9d9fa946-ee6e-408e-9e8a-7a9786a1d362","label":"ACTIVITY", "type":{"id":2}}

**Update**

Activity Repository :

```
@Transactional
public interface ActivityDao extends CrudRepository<Activity, UUID> {

@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Activity a SET a.type = :type WHERE a.uuid = :uuid")
int updateType(@Param("uuid") UUID uuid, @Param("type") ActivityType type);
}
```

Activity Service:

```
@Service
public class ActivityService implements EntityService<Activity,UUID> {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActivityService.class);
    @Override
    public Activity update(Activity activity) {
    LOGGER.info("Update ",activity);
    Activity updated = activityDao.findOne(activity.getUuid());
    if(updated==null) throw new ResourceNotFoundException();

    if (activity.getType().getId()!= updated.getType().getId()) {
        LOGGER.info("Update ActivityType for Activity "+activity.getUuid(),activity);

        activityDao.updateType(updated.getUuid(),activity.getType());
    }
    updated.setLabel(activity.getLabel());
    updated.setDetails(activity.getDetails());

    return activityDao.save(updated);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: a.type is clearly of type ActivityType so you have to pass in an ActivityType. SQLNative queries are the only way to get around that but then your code becomes a non-OO dirty hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your parameter `@Param("type") long type` is wrong !
it should be `@Param("type") ActivityType type`.

Comment: and for your second question : i think it is possible. What are you using for a library to convert from json to java ? jackson ? ... when converting your json, u'll get an Activity object, just save it, as simple as that ... no ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pras. I did but now a new error appears > javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Comment: you are welcome Mezoo, can you post the service in which you are accessing the repository ? and the repository itself ... you are missing a @Transactional somewhere

Comment: Its done, I've updated the post. Transactionnal annotation was present before

Comment: add a @Transactional  on your service method side as well ... and then, can you check if you didn't forget <tx:annotation-driven /> in your spring config file ?

Comment: you should have something like this

 `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
 
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>`

Comment: This is change nothing :(

Comment: okay ... then you have that <tx:annotation-driven /> in your config right ? ... now make sure you use :

org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional annotation

and not 

javax.transaction.Transactional

Comment: Yeah ! You rules ! You right, I used the wrong package ! Many thanks !!